# project/configuration sync from shell (not from ./admin)

Tags: drush, configuration

With project/configuration (core 7.22 and configuration 7.x-2.0-alpha2), we can sync a new database to the exported .inc files via the admin gui, but need to be able to do it from drush.

Specifically, we trying to get to where we can run drush site-install, and then drush sync config, to get content types and other meta-data built, from the project/configuration exported .inc files.

It looks like the heavy lifting is implemented in configuration.module, function configuration_import_directory.  Do we still have to roll our own, to be able to invoke this from the shell?

Answer (score 0):

drush csyn does the job.

we're putting the config files in a non-default location, so need to specify the path:
  drush csyn --source=/path/to/config